# Returning html on submit with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Now, I know there are several questions that may look like this, but in short, I haven't found quite the functionality I need, let alone getting it working. I want to return a confirmation message from messages sent from the forms in the footer of my site as opposed to returning the user to a new page.

**default state**

[image: Default form state]

**after message has been sent**

[image]

#### Form

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Form field 1" />
     <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Form field 2" />
     <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Form field 3" />

     <input type="submit" value="Submit button" />
</form>
```

#### AJAX *-- this is where I get lost*

```
$('#submit_button').click(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'parse.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function ()
        {
            alert('form was submitted');
        }
    });
});
```

In theory, this would call the file `parse.php`, which validates the information, works with a database, and sends a `mail` function. The problem I'm running into is the page returns with an empty form and no alert, nor am I getting any other type of response I would want (php `header('Location: http://google.com')`, etc).

What I'm wondering is, is there something wrong with my javascript, or is it because I need more parameters to my form (`method`, `enctype`...) ?

Comment: There is input with id "submit_button" ??

Comment: What HTML do u want to return?

Comment: You can't use `header('location: ... ')` with AJAX.

Comment: <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit button" /> and don't use alert direct like, `alert('form was submitted');` but depend on response from server alert response, like error response or success response. also `header("Location ....");` this will not work using ajax.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea I wanted to return a `<div>` laid over the form, so I guess returning any standard string to the DOM is pretty much where I was going with this.

Comment: what about an error message? if you are getting no response, have you checked to make sure you are actually getting a successful return?

Comment: Yes, I've also added an error message to my live code -- a successful result redirects to Google's home page, whereas failure goes to Yahoo's website. However, I currently do not have any redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working solution:

**Form**

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Form field 1" />
    <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Form field 2" />
    <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Form field 3" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit button" />
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('form').submit(function()
        {
            $.get('parse.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data)
            {
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**parse.php**

```
if( isset($_REQUEST['field1']) and
    isset($_REQUEST['field2']) and
    isset($_REQUEST['field3']) )
{
    // Headers and other parameters
    $sujet = "Email Subject line";
    $mailto = "my@email.com";

    $headers = "";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Organization: ACNE CO.\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
    $message = "";

    // Info to send
    $field1 = $_REQUEST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_REQUEST['field2'];
    $field3 = $_REQUEST['field3'];
    
    $message .= "Field 1 description: " . $field1 . "<br />";
    $message .= "Field 2 description: " . $field2 . "<br />";
    $message .= "Field 3 description: " . $field3 . "<br />";
    
    mail($mailto, $sujet, $message, $headers);
    
    // Confirmation message
    $confirmation = '<div id="confirmation">Message sent</div>';
    print($confirmation);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**First.**
You missed in your html `id` for element, use this:

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Form field 1" />
     <input type="text" name="field2" placeholder="Form field 2" />
     <input type="text" name="field3" placeholder="Form field 3" />    
     <input type="submit"  id="submit_button"  value="Submit button" /> //here set the id to element
</form>
```

**Second.**
You can use javascript  :

```
success: function ()
{
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
```

to redirect to another page

Comment: I've added the id to my submit. Yet, the redirection does not take place, neither in the database nor do I get any email.

Comment: First: see if you send data to parse.php. Second:iif yes, do what you want? if no, try to find error in you code.

Comment: I've added as an answer my complete solution; your insight has helped (especially the `id` parameter). That was the major issue. As you'll see, the code has changed since the original post, but comments and additional research (with the given feedback) has allowed for better coding. Might not be optimal (as I've said, new to AJAX), but functional nonetheless.

Comment: Great! Hope now there is no problem!)